# Android google calendar permission issue

Tags: android, permissions, google-calendar-api, account

I am using [google-api-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) to access Google calendar.

Following are the permissions in my manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 <uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
 <uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

but I am getting such a warning message on the first run:

---

The following one or more applications request permission to access your account, now and in the future.

- Google
  .....@gmail.com
- Google Calendar

Do you want to allow this request?

---

screenshot:

[image]

is there a way to avoid this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot avoid this message, this is to let the users know what applications are doing with their data.