# Android Authentication Mananger, when is user permission required?

Tags: java, android, access-token, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-authenticator

I am writing an Android App and I need to request an Auth token from the account. Getting the list of accounts and the token is easy, I have that working so far.

The problem is that Jelly Bean opens a popup, asking for users permission. Now my question(s):

1. What are the rules for the popup dialog to appear? I had that happen once, for the first time after I updated my device to Android 4.1. It seem to happen randomly: installing and uninstalling the App I was not be able to reproduce the situation where this popup comes back.
2. Is there any way to reset it without doing factory reset? I need to reproduce this for testing for question 3.)
3. Is there a way to find out if the popup will appear **before** requesting the authtoken and i.e. wait until it's not required anymore (i.e, if user has the app in question installed but never used or if authtoken is expired?) and request it then?

   I know that most Android users are very inexperienced and may get scared by some permission requests and I'd like to avoid requesting authtoken when it would trigger this user popup.

Comment: Is this the popup you are asking about?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965126/android-google-calendar-permission-issue

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes. This is the popup that came up, just with different Google Service.

But it never cam back, no matter how often I deleted the app and reinstalled it

Answer (score 3):

I Tried to revoke acces to an app engine project of mine and I was able to revoke the permission by going to google accounts setting page. There you can revoke access from android login service. After that I had to remove the google account from my phone and add it back. If you start your app again you should see the permission dialog again.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting/revoking the permission generally depend on the type of token. There are two sides of this: revoking the token on the server side using your Google profile page and revoking the permission for your app to use this type of token (on Android). For the server side you can revoke OAuth and AuthSub tokens, but not ClientLogin tokens. Go to https://www.google.com/settings/security and click the 'Edit' button in the 'Authorizing applications and sites' section. For revoking the on device permission, uninstalling the your app should reset it (it removes an entry in a system database when your package is uninstalled). Apparently this doesn't work properly on some devices, but it *should* work. The dialog will only appear when you try to use a token, so it shouldn't appear before you request it. You should handle expiry in your app (i.e., request a fresh token), but this won't show a permission dialog.

Comment: Thanks, tested uninstalling on Nexus 7, Samsung Galaxy Nexus and others but it didn't revoke the permission. I'm requesting permission for the Google Cloud Print service (OAUTH2 token) but on the server side the only Authorized access entry was 'Android Login Service'. Removing this resulted in credentials having to be re-entered on the device but the permission screen was not re-shown.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Not sure where Cloud Print is managed. Maybe the API console? There must be some place where you can revoke tokens. As for on device permissions, this is how it used to worked, maybe it has been changed on JB, haven't checked in detail.